# How do I strongly suggest the size of a <div></div>?

Tags: html

I have a web page that is laid out in HTML and has some Silverlight imbeded into the main portion.  This Silverlight needs to be absolutely positioned on the screen for reasons out side the scope of this question.  In order to maintain the flow of the HTML which is statically positioned I wrote the code below.

```
<div id="div2" style="height:600;width:900;">
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

I understand that this is a major hack but I'm not sure if there is a better way to handle this.  Thank you for any answers.

Aaron

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Why do you need all the `<br />`?

Comment: My guess is that his height is not behaving as expecting... but that's only a guess.

Comment: Indeed, but as long as he hasn't changed the `div` default from `display: block` the size will be "strongly suggested" by the style.

Comment: The CSS won't do that without px - at least, not in browsers of which I have a copy. Google Chrome, which I happen to be using now, completely ignores heights without units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that your CSS is wrong? Heights and widths should be `px` for reliable rendering.

HTML:

```
<div id="div2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div2 { height: 600px; width: 900px; }
```

Unitless heights are ignored in all browsers for which I tested. (Even IE6 doesn't do it *that* wrong.)

Comment: Isn't `px` the default unit if no unit is specified? I remember having read this somewhere but I am not quite sure anymore...

Comment: If some browsers do this, it's definitely not part of the spec. My copy of Firefox and Google Chrome ignore unitless heights, but maybe Internet Explorer has different behavior.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just checked this: According to CSS spec omitting the unit is only allowed if the value is zero. (I confused it with entering Width and Height attributes for ASP.NET controls where you can omit the unit. But then the rendered HTML automatically adds a `px` to the value of the style.) Sorry!

Comment: No apologies :) I'm sure it's a huge misconception among new CSSers.

Comment: This was my problem.  Thank you! Thank you for not making fun of me when I put in a crap-load of <div> tags.  ;)

Comment: Specifically, IE allows non-0 unitless lengths in Quirks Mode only. In Standards Mode it ignores them (except in places where unitless lengths have a defined meaning, like line-height).

Comment: Haha. I thought I remembered IE6 behaving that way, but it didn't when I checked - that's why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just put a `<div style="margin-top:a lot;">static content goes here</div>`?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you set position:absolute?

Comment: To position the Silverlight content in the body, which may/may not be a good idea depending on the situation